# How to fetch data from table Using Like cluse in store procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Here i want to fetch some result from table for that I i have writter Sp as like below.

```
create proc GetData
(
@tableName nvarchar(max),
@groupLetter nvarchar(max)
)
as
begin
    EXEC('Select * from ' + @tablename + 'where LastName LIKE'''+'%'+@groupLetter+'%'+'''ORDER BY LastName') 
end
```

to this SP i am passing  table name and the text to find a result.
this create SP successfully but gives error while executing it.

this is the way i executes SP.
    EXEC GetData Employees,ab

and am getting error as below.
**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a syntax error in your string (not enough spaces). It should be:

```
begin
    EXEC('Select * from ' + @tablename + ' where LastName LIKE '''+'%'+@groupLetter+'%'+''' ORDER BY LastName') 
end
```

Comment: yep,
I was very close.
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'Select * from ' + @tablename + N' where LastName LIKE '''+N'%'+@groupLetter+N'%'+N''' ORDER BY LastName'

EXEC(@sql);
```

The first error that you had was you missed some spaces between keywords of your query, the second error: `exec` does not accept string concatenation so you should construct your query in a variable and then pass it into `exec`.